# Problem with sending ERC20 token using web3@1.0.0

Tags: web3js, erc-20, ethereumjs, infura, ethereumjs-tx

### Circumstance

I have followed all indications from this GH [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1151) and from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180941/send-erc20-token-with-web3/50019666#50019666) SO posts. The transaction gets successfully [broadcasted](http://0x836ab053ff8d3c901a0ec8f535d4391b8b8c7821b23641dd37731bff31f07273) but no tokens are transferred.

When I check the balance before and after running the code, I get the same result: 10000, which is the original supply.

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

const config = require('../config');
const contract = require('../contract')('PaulCoin', config.contracts[0]);
const web3 = require('../web3');

const main = async () => {
    try {
        const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(config.accounts[0]);
        const nonce = web3.utils.toHex(count);
        const txValue = web3.utils.toHex(parseInt(process.argv[2], 10) || 10);

        const from = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(config.accounts[0]);

        const to = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(config.accounts[1]);
        const rawTx = {
            nonce: nonce,
            from: from,
            to: to,
            value: '0x0',
            gasLimit: '0x30D40', // 54,000
            gasPrice: '0x2CB417800', // 12 gwei
            data: contract.methods.transfer(to, txValue).encodeABI(),
            chainId: '0x03'
        };

        const privateKey = Buffer.from(config.private, 'hex');
        const tx = new Tx(rawTx);
        tx.sign(privateKey);
        const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
        console.log(`Receipt info:  ${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}`);

        console.log(`From\'s balance after transfer: ${await contract.methods.balanceOf(from).call()}`);
        console.log(`To\'s balance after transfer: ${await contract.methods.balanceOf(to).call()}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

main();
```

### Environment

- node `9.3.0`
- web3 `1.0.0-beta.35`
- infura `ropsten`
- os `osx 13.13.5`

Comment: at what block was your transaction mined?

Comment: first thing I would do, is to get the block number, get the transaction input and decode it, check that the value transferred is not 0

Comment: Just checked now, it's not 0, but `a` or 10 in decimal, just as it should. You can check out the [tx](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x836ab053ff8d3c901a0ec8f535d4391b8b8c7821b23641dd37731bff31f07273) and the [contract](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PaulRBerg/paulcoin/master/contracts/Escrow.sol) yourself.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code for the contract? It doesn't appear to have a function called `transfer`.

Comment: Oh, actually, the transaction isn't being sent to a contract at all. The `to` address is https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x19149798f777a3d738777334ccbf0063a04fca3b, which is not a contract. (There's no associated code.)

Comment: @smarx sorry I wanted to attach a link to [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PaulRBerg/paulcoin/master/contracts/PaulCoin.sol) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x836ab053ff8d3c901a0ec8f535d4391b8b8c7821b23641dd37731bff31f07273) is being sent to the address [`0x19149798f777a3d738777334ccbf0063a04fca3b`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x19149798f777a3d738777334ccbf0063a04fca3b), which is not a contract.

No ERC20 transfer occurs because no transaction was sent to an ERC20 token contract.

Comment: It [worked](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x70ef1d1fe5446194ae73ebcafa200663895b351e5814772e37630381d65a8c4e) like a charm now. Kudos!